# What Job Title Suits What I Do At Work?

Tags: job-change, title

I'm in this job in a small company and my job title is just "Assistant"

However, the person I was assisting has left for over half a year already, and I've been doing more than just assisting. I do the following:

1. Data imports/feeds
2. Coding/programming of our release products (data collection software etc)
3. Overseeing/coding/programming the automation of business processes (company has a lot of manual processes and processes that can be automated)
4. Database development/management

What job title can I ask for, as I haven't had an appraisal for the year I've been working for this company?

I was thinking of a title in `Database` and `Development` like:

```
Software and Database Developer
Business Process Automation Engineer
```

Primarily because I am doing software development as well as database development and process automation. I'm coming up with ideas and implementing them after getting approval. Also, I am automating the processes that are manual and improving them.

What I used to do and what my employment was meant to cover was just being a backup to someone for data imports and a little coding here and there, and to just be support hence the title "Assistant" - I've been doing so much more since.

I don't know what to do. Am I, at the end of the day, just a Software Engineer? A Database Developer? A VBA Expert (I have been automating a lot of spreadsheet work with VBA)? I also just got word that in BPA (Business Process Automation) it is a lot of just designing the automation and not the actual coding/programming (which I do) so perhaps BPA is out of the question. I don't know how to title myself so that it will also help me when I look for another job (if I do have to leave this job)

I really could use a lot of help! Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a technical business analyst to me... Also a dev... Also a Data specialist

Comment: chief cook and bottle washer?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to read a few job specs of potentially similar roles and see how your responsibilities match up and use that as a basis for determining what title would be most appropriate.

Comment: Data Analyst is the common title. Database Engineer is sometimes also used but you should have a degree with a database specialization for that.

Comment: ['What am I' questions are off topic.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/are-what-am-i-questions-too-localised)

Comment: i'd really just say "developer" or "database developer".

Answer (score 2):

***Software engineer*** fits the bill, in my book : it's broad, and when people ask you questions, you may detail the content.

The DBA developper is a software engineer, the VBA expert is a software engineer(though if it's just for a few months, you're certainly far from expert level), automating processes is software engineering.

Comment: I'd generally agree with this - Software Developer, Software Engineer etc are good generic terms. The more specific a job title gets, the more I suspect they actually just write a bit of SQL and are padding their resume.